# Why am I not able to load a module from within embedded JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, ejs

My objective is to store some data in a module and then be able to retrieve
that data for display using embedded javascript contained in an HTML document.  My code for testing this is shown in the following 3 files:

File 1: The HTML (/var/www/html/modTest.html)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Module Test</title>
  <% var myModule = require("/var/www/cgi-bin/node_modules/modTest") %>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Color: <%= myModule.color %>
 </body>
</html>
```

File 2: The Module (/var/www/cgi-bin/node_modules/modTest.js)

```
var color = "Blue";
module.exports.color = color;
```

File 3: The CGI Script (/var/www/cgi-bin)

```
#!/bin/node
var fs = require("fs");
var ejs = require("ejs")
console.log("Content-type: text/html\n");console.log(ejs.render(fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/modTest.html','utf8')));
```

When I load the URL of the cgi script into my browser I get a blank page.  There is an error message in the httpd error log compaining that "require" is not defined.  Can anyone please tell me why this is and (more importantly) how to fix it?  Thanks for any input.

```
   ... doug
```

Answer (score 1):

you need require.js or webpack/browserify to link/pack your javascript together for client side and to load your modules with a require - otherwise you would need to include every javascript file in as a

```
<script src="...">
```

tag seperately.